# How can I add an Image in Messenger Chat?

Tags: html, css, image, text, chat

In my chat, I would like to have a text message displayed in the balloon for one button and an image from my gallery for the other button. The programming for the text works. How do I get this with the picture?

My HTML Code is this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<div class="Webview">

  <div class="message_container" id="myForm" >
          <div class="Chat_Bubble"></div>
  </div>


  <form class="send_container">
    <input id="textField" type="text">
    <img id="Bildverschicken" src="baseline_image_black_18dp.png">
    <p>
    <input type ="button" id="theButton" value="Nachricht absenden!"
    onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('Chat_Bubble')[0].textContent=document.getElementById('textField').value"/>
  </p>
  <input type="button" id="Button_Bilder" value="Bild verschicken!"
  onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('Chat_Bubble')[0].imageContent=document.getElementById('Bildverschicken').value"/>
 <h3><div id="div"></div></h3>
  </form>



</div>
```

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you put your code in the snippet?

Comment: Look at my Answer below your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

.Webview{
  height: 600px;
  width: 380px;
}

.message_container{
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  border:5px solid green;
}

.Chat_Bubble{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;

  background: #95c2fd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.15, #bee2ff), color-stop(1, #95c2fd));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #bee2ff 15%, #95c2fd 100%);
  border: solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.65), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 8px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.65), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 8px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.65), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.bubble:before, .bubble:after {
  border-radius: 20px / 5px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.bubble:before {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -7px;
  z-index: -2;
}

.bubble:after {
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #bee2ff; /* arrow color */
  bottom: 1px;
  left: -5px;
}


.bubble-alt {
  float: right;
}
.bubble-alt:before {
  left: auto;
  right: -7px;
}
.bubble-alt:after {
  left: auto;
  right: -5px;
}

.bubble p {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
}

.send_container{
  height: 20;
  width: 100%;
}

.send_container input{
  width: 70%;
  height:20%
  border:2px solid #1CE615;
}

.send_container button{
  width: 30%;
  height:20%;
}

.send_container Button_Bilder{
  width: 10%;
  height:10% ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<div class="Webview">

  <div class="message_container" id="myForm" >
          <div class="Chat_Bubble"></div>
  </div>


  <form class="send_container">
    <input id="textField" type="text">
    <img id="Bildverschicken" src="baseline_image_black_18dp.png">
    <p>
    <input type ="button" id="theButton" value="Nachricht absenden!"
    onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('Chat_Bubble')[0].textContent=document.getElementById('textField').value"/>
  </p>
  <input type="button" id="Button_Bilder" value="Bild verschicken!"
  onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('Chat_Bubble')[0].imageContent=document.getElementById('Bildverschicken').value"/>
 <h3><div id="div"></div></h3>
  </form>



</div>
```